# When did Luffy say: "Forgetting is like a wound.The wound may heal, but it has already left a scar."?

Tags: one-piece

I came across the quote online. Every site says that the [quotee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quotee) is Monkey D Luffy.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could point me to an anime/manga source for the quote.

Comment: It looks like there is no trace of this quote before ~20 March 2015 (from what i searched), so the episode could be within this date

Comment: I think he might be saying this line to Rebecca.

Comment: IIRC, Jinbei said this just before donating his blood to luffy

Comment: @Dimitrimx That's not it. He did speak about hurting and getting hurt though. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgDQgFlMxbw) is the scene you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, **Luffy never said this quote**.

And I am up to the Doflamingo Arc, And still never heard Luffy state this, its probably some quote made up from the fans.