# When did Luffy from One Piece say this?

Tags: one-piece, quotes

“no matter how hard or impossible it is, never lose sight of your goal” it seems to be quoted everywhere but I can’t find the episode or chapter where Luffy actually says this.

Comment: There's a possibility that it's a fictitious quote, similar to [this another quote by Luffy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28263/2516).

Comment: That said, based on [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22no+matter+how+hard+or+impossible+it+is%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2010%2Ccd_max%3A2013), the oldest record was in November 2011. Based on that date, it should be before the [Punk Hazard anime arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_One_Piece_episodes) and [manga volume 65](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_One_Piece_manga_volumes).

Comment: He never said this, searched everywhere...